# Crystal Reports: ways to divert report data source based on the user parameters?

Tags: crystal-reports

I am working on this report that has a stored procedure and a table (for showing the zero values) for its data source. I am looking for a way to separate the report data based on the user parameter selections.

For example, if a user selects a predefined parameter "A", then the report is to obtain data from the stored procedure alone. If, however, a user selects a parameter "B", then the report needs to obtain the data from the stored procedure and the table.

I know it sounds like a mess, but I am not to modify the stored procedure and find a way to do this in the reports.

Any idea or suggestion that I can try? Is there a way to accomplish this in the Command window?

Answer (score 0):

Check this [SAP Support](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3726602) about changing a Crystal Report datasource at runtime.